# Failed to fetch URL in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, add-in, failed-installation

I have downloaded the Android SDK and installed the Android Development Tools in Eclipse.

Now when I try to add `Third Party Add-ons` in the `Android SDK and AVD Manager` I get this :

[image: Failed to fetch URL]

I have already set the path to the Android SDK, and tried to disable the firewall, and even I started `SDK Manager` from the command promopt. Nothing has corrected the problem yet.

What's this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using http rather than https ?

Comment: Change your URL from https to http as suggested by Matt Colliss.

Comment: Still no accepted answers?  Yes, I have the exact same problem (except running on a Mac)--and changing https to http doesn't solve anything. By the error message, it says, "file not found." **Where is the file?**  And more importantly: where is the information that tells where that file is (so we can track it down when it changes again)?

Comment: No answer yet, I moved to Windows Phone development now. and very happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem, and I resolved.
in the Eclipse click "help" -> "Check for Updates"
The problem is solved after update
Android SDK and AVD Manager separated into Android SDK Manager and AVD Manager Now

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu linux 12.04 sdk 7 
I had to delete the .android FILE in my home directory, 
create a .android DIRECTORY
create a .android/cache directory

then re run the tool, I was initially going to manually download the files into the cache directory as specified by the android sdk tool.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your settings or options check the force https option and make sure that the http proxy server textbox is empty.